# Easy way to export/import last N rows of a cassandra table

Tags: cassandra

Is this possible? I don't care about the intermediate format as long as it's of a reasonable size. I'm trying to export-import about 2-3k rows from each table (think: an event log).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you want do but the tool described here might help.
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/sstable2json

If you want do in your code you can iterate over rows using a KeyRange -- if you know from which row to start you can do something like this ...

[example using Pelops client]

```
KeyRange current_keyrange = Selector.newKeyRange(myStartRowKey, "", 2000);
```

if you have no idea where to start you should iterate - starting from a KeyRange like this

```
KeyRange current_keyrange = Selector.newKeyRange("", "", 2000);
```

Hope this helps,
Carlo

Comment: `sstable2json` does not support row ranges AFAIK, and the question title says: Easy way to export/import **last N rows**

Comment: AFAIK last "N" rows depends on your partitioner configuration (Random, OPP, other?) -- so I don't think there is a "native way" to do it (I could be wrong) -- A  solution could be to create a custom row that keep track of the latest rows inserted (each time you write a row you add a column in this particular row) - then you read from there to take the latest X columns. I'd use TimeUUID columns in order to keep them sorted. Hope this helps, Carlo